# Android: Characters left countdown in EditText

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext

I have this EditText with a limit of 150 characters:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:maxLength="150"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.8"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences" >
</EditText>
```

TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
 />
```

NewActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class NewActivity extends Activity {




private TextView textView1;
private EditText editText1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_text);


    final ImageButton a = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageBack);
    a.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Animation anim =              AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(NewActivity.this, R.anim.animation);
            a.startAnimation(anim);

            Intent intent = new Intent(NewActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
            {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int aft)                                                                           
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
                {
                   // this will show characters remaining
                    textView1.setText(150 - s.toString().length() + "/150");
                }
            });


        }
    });




}}
```

I want to create a small box in the top right corner of the page where you can see how many characters there is left, for example 132/150, i have tried looking at others solutions here on stackoverflow but i couldnt get them to work.

Comment: For best UX, you shouldn't set maximum length of text while user is editing it, because posting can become inconvent. Give the user possibility to write as long as he wants, then, if he wrote more than allowed, he should edit the post into more compact. Twitter as a reference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int aft                                                                           
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
       // this will show characters remaining
        countTextView.setText(150 - s.toString().length() + "/150");
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but i get "countTextView" cannot be resolved"?

Comment: It is the `TextView` that you will show on the top right part of your activity

Comment: should i make a new textview to show the "counttextview"?

Comment: If you already have one just change the name from countTextView to what you have used

Comment: the error is gone now but the textview inside the app is just blank and doesnt show characters left?

Comment: Did you try typing in the `EditText`?

Comment: Did you assign the `EditText` and `TextView` ids and there are no other errors?

Comment: Yes i replaced the "mEditText" with "editText1" and the "countTextView" with "textView1"

Comment: Can you post your code and xml file in the question?

Comment: You haven't assigned anything to `editText1` and `textView1` plus you need to move the code out of the `onClickListener` or it will never start unless you click on the `ImageButton`

Comment: thanks! sorry for asking so much but how should i assign them?

Comment: Same as you did with `ImageButton a`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TextWatcher to see when the text has changed

```
private TextView mTextView;
private EditText mEditText;
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           //This sets a textview to the current length
           mTextView.setText(String.valueOf(s.length()));
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
};
```

You can set the TextWatcher for the edittext with

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```

Comment: thanks but i get this error: "Illegal modifier for parameter mTextEditorWatcher; only final is permitted"

Answer (score 1):

Programatically do it like..

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            int length = s.length();
            // set this length/maxlength to the textview at the top left
            // corner
            textView.setText(""+length+ "/" +max);//which is placed at the top right corner
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Don't forget to use try/catch clauses in 'setText'

Comment: You'll see negative counter. ok

Comment: @FranklinHirata until the textview is null it wont throw any exception..know programming first where it is required and where not..see other three answer no one is placed..based upon requirement and we will place..

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Keep a TextWatcher and track the length of entered text.
> 2. Do MAX_LENGTH - yourTextwatcherString.length;
> 3. Keep updating the view on the RHS top based on a timer/ or on even key press, your wish (there are several ways to do that). Check, whether old length and new length are not the same before updating the view.

Comment: thanks, could you show an example of how i could write the code?